# How use ReactJS with Craft CMS (mainly just looking to use on client side)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, craftcms

I'm quite new to React, so this might just be down to inexperience.

Im looking to use React to replace the templates, css and js of a website built with Craft CMS. Does anyone have any experience with React and Craft CMS that can give me guidance in the process?

(I have guessed I'll need to get twig working in a React component file, and point the Craft CMS backend to both the development React and the build React.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the graphQL plugin or the element API and then get your CRAFT CMS content over an API request into your react app. Thats the way to separate backend from frontend.